# Como puedo pasar a terniario y luego anidarlos?

Tags: java-8

espero que se encuentren bien! estoy intentando convertir esta linea en terniario y luego de ahi anidarlos juntos para que se cumpla, ¿Alguna idea?, gracias por el apoyo, saludos!

```
if(parameterIn.get("amount")!=null
                    && util.validateAmount((double) parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue()))){
            }else if (parameterIn.get("amount")== null){


if(parameterIn.get("date")!=null
                    && util.validateDate((String) parameterIn.get(Constants.DATE.getValue()))){
            }else if (util.dateNull((String)parameterIn.get("date"))){  
            }
```

Este es un ejemplo que tuve con el primer if, pero no se si este bien!

```
Boolean var1 = (parameterIn.get("amount")==null
                    || util.validateAmount((double) parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue())))
                            || (parameterIn.get("amount")== null)?  true:false;
```

Comment: El operador ternario se usa para devolver algún valor o resultado, en tu caso, ¿cuál sería el valor a obtener?

Comment: si diculpa! seria un resultado en true y false!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para empezar, algunas herramientas de calidad no recomiendan el uso de ternarios dado que se dice que "dificulta" la lectura del código (smell code), pero de todas formas se puede realizar así:

```
Boolean var1 = parameterIn.get("amount")!=null
                    && util.validateAmount((double) 
               parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue())) ? 
               true : 
              (parameterIn.get("amount")== null ? true : false);
```

se puede anidar y funciona pero el problema es que dificulta la legibilidad del código

Comment: Puedo preguntarte algo mas? o tengo que abrir otra pergunta en la pagina! gracias

Comment: Creo que acá es por pregunta, igual puedes crear la pregunta y alguien de la comunidad amablemente te contestará